# Finding scroll bottom issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've been trying to detect that the scroll is at the bottom of a div with this code:

```js
   $('.scrollpane').scroll(function(){
  
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() === $("#results").height()) {
   alert('scroll at bottom');
  }

    });
```

```css
.scrollpane
 {
     height: 400px;
     overflow: auto;
     width: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollpane">
  <ul id="results">
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
   <li>item4</li>
   <li>item5</li>
   <li>item6</li>
   <li>item7</li>
   <li>item8</li>
   <li>item9</li>
   <li>item10</li>
   <li>item11</li>
   <li>item12</li>
   ...
            <li>item39</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

but getting this log when div is scrolled to bottom:

scrollpane height + scrollpane scrollTop = 740.9090881347656

content height = 709.091

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited from the original answer, after some JSfiddling:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oden8y3/42/)

```
  var resultHeight = $('#results').innerHeight();
  var scrollPaneHeight = $('.scrollpane').innerHeight();
  var marginBottom =parseInt($('#results').css('marginBottom').replace('px', ''));
  var marginTop =parseInt($('#results').css('marginTop').replace('px', ''));
  var diff = (resultHeight-scrollPaneHeight)+marginBottom+marginTop;

  $('.scrollpane').scroll(function(){
     if ($(this).scrollTop() == diff) {
        alert('scroll at bottom');
     }

  });
```

Explanation:

When overflowed, scrollTop() of scrollPane changes depending on your div height.
You have to figure out its value.

This value equals to the diff variable (the trick is handling the margin, maybe there's a easiest way to do it but I'm done with it now).

So you have to check that your scrollTop takes the diff value.

Comment: I see, the margins have to be calculated as well. The code works in Jsfiddle, but not on chrome. Had to apply math.ceil() on scrollTop and math.floor() on diff. I'll edit the original code with the solution. Thanks for your answer !!

Answer (score 0):

```
let resultHeight = $('#results').innerHeight();
let scrollPaneHeight = $('.scrollpane').innerHeight();
let marginBottom =parseInt($('#results').css('marginBottom'));
let marginTop =parseInt($('#results').css('marginTop'));
let diff = Math.floor((resultHeight-scrollPaneHeight)+marginBottom+marginTop);

$('.scrollpane').scroll(function()
{
    let scrollTop = Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop());

    if (scrollTop == diff || scrollTop == diff + 1)
    {
        alert('scroll at bottom');
    }

});
```